# Merging all cell arrays into one for crossval in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct, cell, cells

I'm working in *Matlab*, I used cell arrays to handle different sort of data, however I want to merge all the cell arrays into one at the end of operation, or possibly some other approach that can avoid to use multiple cell arrays (may be `struct` can do this but I don't know how).

**My Code:**

```
 for ii = 1:10
    pp{ii,1}=ii;
    for jj = 1:6
        p1{jj} = jj;
        pp1{jj} = p1{jj}+1;
        p2{jj} =jj^2;
        pp2{jj} = p2{jj}+1;
        p3{jj} = jj^3;
        pp3{jj} = p3{jj}+1;

    end
    p{ii,1} = ([pp(ii,:),pp1,pp2,pp3])';
    p{ii,2} = (['T' num2str(ii)]);    
end
```

**Actual Output:**

```
p = 

    {19x1 cell}    'T1' 
    {19x1 cell}    'T2' 
    {19x1 cell}    'T3' 
    {19x1 cell}    'T4' 
    {19x1 cell}    'T5' 
    {19x1 cell}    'T6' 
    {19x1 cell}    'T7' 
    {19x1 cell}    'T8' 
    {19x1 cell}    'T9' 
    {19x1 cell}    'T10'
```

Desired Output:
At every `p{1,1}` `p{1,2}`merges in the cell i.e it makes `{19x2 cell}` and at the end, all cell arrays are merge into one single cell array.

P.S: What are the suggestions to make my approach efficient as I'v to put some time consuming operations.

**EDIT 1:**

I want to input `data` and its `label` to `crossval` thats what I'm going for that.
Also, how to separate this to `training` and `test` data when I have the command of `crossval('mcr', data, label, 'predfun', @trainingANDtesting, 'kfold', length(label))`

Comment: did you had a look at `cell2mat`?

Comment: @thewaywewalk yeah, It couldn't help for me. is it possible to avoid multiple cell arrays in my case, i.e by indexing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your right, this looks like a job for structs. Try this:

```
for ii = 1:10
    pp{ii,1}=ii;
    for jj = 1:6
        p1{jj} = jj;
        pp1{jj} = p1{jj}+1;
        p2{jj} =jj^2;
        pp2{jj} = p2{jj}+1;
        p3{jj} = jj^3;
        pp3{jj} = p3{jj}+1;

    end
    p(ii).data = ([pp(ii,:),pp1,pp2,pp3])';
    p(ii).label = (['T' num2str(ii)]);
end
```

Now, both columns of your cell are addressable by a single number: the index. To access the data, do this:

```
myData = p(5).data
myLabel = p(5).label
```

I hope this is what you're looking for. If not, let me know and I'll try again.

Edit 1: Ok, how about this:

```
p{ii,1} = [([pp(ii,:),pp1,pp2,pp3])'; (['T' num2str(ii)])]
```

Or, alternately:

```
data = ([pp(ii,:),pp1,pp2,pp3])';
label = (['T' num2str(ii)]);
p{ii} = [data; label]
```

Comment: unfortunately not. I dont want to access by index, I just need a simple cell array having first column of all the cell arrays and second for all the labels which are repeating for same previous cell array.

Comment: Ok, I posted an edit, which may or may not be useful. Humble suggestion: what you're doing seems to be mixing data types, if possible consider refactoring to keep them distinct, as in my original answer. It's a pretty good practice that's been useful to me. Just my $0.02.

Comment: I want to merge all the cell arrays with their respective labels as I want to input to `crossval` with one column of `data` and other for `label`. The edited answer also not supportive for me.

Comment: Ah, I'll do some research. You should include that bit in the original question.

Comment: Updated my question as per your suggestion. Kindly check.